# How can I set Qmail to relay all mail to one address

Tags: email

I'm new to qmail it's setup and working like it should.  I need to set it to do something a bit different.

I need it to take all mail that would be incoming to it and relay all of that to one address as opposed to whatever address they could have possibly set it to.  The idea is we have setup a test enviroment and we want no e-mails from a test server to actually go out to real people so this relay server will catch all of that outgoing mail and throw it into a test e-mail account inbox to check for errors and so forth.

I'm honestly not sure if this is even possible so if it's not let me know now so I can come up with a different method to manage all these test e-mails.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do that with `/var/qmail/control/smtproutes`. The following would route all outbound emails for `domain.com` to `relay.mail.com`:

```
domain.com:relay.mail.com
```

In order to route all emails to `relay.mail.com`, use the following:

```
:relay.mail.com
```

Comment: I think my question might be a bit confusing.  We are trying to get all the e-mail messages that would go to this test server to be fowarded to one e-mail address.  Basically some sort of rule that ignores the TO line in the e-mail and sends it all to a specific e-mail address.